# How often is the keyboard polled for the Form.KeyDown event?

Tags: c#, .net, events, keyboard

I'm running a program at 45 frames per second. It's a game, so timely user input is important. It would seem that the keydown event sometimes performs... slowly? As if the polling interval varies by sometimes up to 3 or 4 seconds. I'm absolutely sure that the actual game isn't lagging, but rather the input is.
I plan on moving to GetKeyState(), but I'd still like to know the actual polling frequency for the KeyDown event.

EDIT: Thought I'd post a link to the workaround I'm using [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/winforms-accessing-mouse-and-keyboard-state).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no polling frequency -- Windows uses a messaging system to deliver keypresses (and other event notifications) to applications.

The physical keypress triggers an interrupt which makes its way into the OS, which eventually sends a message to your program.

The lag you're seeing might be because of the event-queue being a shared service in Windows (i.e. Windows is sending the message a little after it occurred when there's a load on the system). 3-4 seconds is a *lot* of lag, though -- I'm not sure what could be causing it.

See [this article](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38447) for more information.

Comment: +1. The delay @Bloodyaugust is experiencing is probably because the game isn't processing messages properly.

Comment: @Ken: Could you explain how it might not be processing messages properly? Isn't .Net handling all the message handling behind the scenes?

Comment: Is it common for it to lag through said queue even with relatively low load?

Comment: @Bloodyaugust: I don't have any sources, but I'd say 3-4 seconds is really extra-terrible lag -- I once used Windows messages to communicate between threads and the lag was unnoticeable, even on a heavily-loaded system. I'm not sure what your lag is caused by...

Comment: @ Cameron: Possibly because I'm calling Application.DoEvents() 45 times per second? Oh wait, that should fix it... >_<

Comment: @Bloodyaugust: Aha! That would explain it ;-)